# Postgres Won't Start - incomplete startup packet

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have an issue that is preventing a Postgres server from starting.  The server fell over after it ran out of disk space, how ever this has now been resolved although now Postgres will not start.  It just keep writing the same lines to the log file as shown below.

It is not a cluster, it is a single Postgres server.   Does anyone have any ideas what to look at here?

Using Postgres 9.3

```
2015-02-23 17:49:35 UTC LOG:  redo starts at 75/202674D8
2015-02-23 17:49:35 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-02-23 17:49:36 UTC FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-02-23 17:49:36 UTC FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-02-23 17:49:41 UTC FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-02-23 17:49:41 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

** UPDATE **

I ran strace on the running pid and I can see that it is getting a "Temporary resource in use" error when trying to access a file in the pg_clog dir.

Comment: `It is not a cluster, it is a single Postgres server.` That's a misunderstanding. Postgres *always* operates with a db cluster, even if there is only a single db.

Comment: My mistake.. but it is a single server that has failed so right now the DB is offline.   I ran strace on the running pid and I can see that it is getting a "Temporary resource in use" error when trying to access a file in the pg_clog dir.

Comment: If nobody can assist here, consider posting your question to pgsql-admin@postgresql.org. Here's the mail archive: http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-admin/

Comment: Will do, thanks Erwin. I'm out of ideas here